# Rest-client Ruby HLS API library: How to extract a url from and HLS stream response and use a specific url as variable for future request

Tags: ruby, rest, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, rest-client

```
require 'rest-client'

response = RestClient.get 'http://......',
                      params:
                          { deviceType: '..',
                            deviceMake: '..',
                            deviceVersion: '..',
                            deviceId: '..',
                            appVersion: '..',
                            deviceDNT: '..',
                            deviceModel: '..',
                            sid: '..' }

print response.body
```

So when I print this I see the response in my IDE (or curl from terminal) which lists 4 urls. I need to grab 1 of those URL's and use it for a new future request. How do I go about extrapolating data and use it for future request

not that it matters but using Rubymine IDE.

RESPONSE of the body when I print it from IDE Run:

## EXTM3U

## EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=997452

http://.....

## EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1539795

http://.....

## EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2142297

http://......

## EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=3063648

http://......

## EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=572723

http://......

Comment: Can you add an example of the response you get?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma Edited main question to include response.

Comment: Are you receiving a JSON response?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma seems like it's just a RAW response. Can't tell... but the request header is:                                                                      
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://...........
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1674
Content-Type: application/x-mpegurl; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 05 Jul 2017 19:29:59 GMT
Etag: W/"68a-yP3L6LkpAW7J30ubTAOYow"
X-Powered-By: Express

Comment: Sorry if I bother you, what do you get in a terminal if you run your script? I'm not sure if the IDE is formatting your output.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma when I curl the url through terminal comes same way. I'll reedit main question with response from terminal

Comment: @SebastiánPalma It's an HLS response https://smoothscaling.com/load-testing-hls-with-ruby-jmeter-85b9b1e6db72  go down to the HLS section and you'll get an idea. This is the specs https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-13